# How to get JQuery to check If XML node is empty and echo back statement if it is

Tags: jquery, xml

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    runningPrinters();
    fetch();    
});

function fetch() {
    setTimeout( function(){
        runningPrinters();
        fetch();
    }, 100);
}

function runningPrinters() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"runningPrinters.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            $("table").children().remove();
            $(data).find("Printer").each( function(){
                var info = '<tr><td> ' + $(this).attr('id') + '</td>       <td>Status:' + $(this).find("Status").text() + '</td></tr>';
                $("table").append(info);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Basically this is what I have so far but I need the status to echo that it's empty when it's empty and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) can check if element is empty or not:

```
if ($(this).find("Status").is(':empty')){
   info = ...
else
{
  info =!...

}
```